# Reverse engineering SSIS package using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, reverse-engineering, etl

There is a requirement to extract `source`,`destination` and `column` names of `source` and `destination`. Why am I trying to do this is because I have thousands of packages and opening each package has on an average `60 to 75` of columns and listing all required info will take huge amount of time and its not a single time requirement and this task is done manually every two months in my organization currently.

I'm looking for some ways to reverse engineer keeping all packages in a single folder and then go through each package and get the info and put it in some spreadsheet.

I thought of opening package in `xml` and get the info of interested node and put in spreadsheet which is little cumbersome. Please suggest what are the available libraries to start with it.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Hadi. The link will save multifold man efforts. :)

Comment: @Yahfoufi Did you check the first link provided in the accepted answer?

Comment: I provided a script that list all objects, i will try later to create a small application that visualize the results.

Comment: @Nkosi i think that the script is outdated since it is related to SQL Server 2000-2005 (DTS and SSIS 2005).

Comment: @Hadi thanks for the update i will take a look

Comment: @Yahfoufi do you need a solution that can handle *any* source and destination or would a subset, like ole source to ole destination suffice?

Comment: @billinkc i need to list all Tasks and Components, The updated answer below is all what i need

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*SQL server provide assemblies to manipulate packages programmatically.*

To do a reverse engineering *(deserialize a dtsx package)*, You have to do this by looping over packages and read them programmatically, just follow this detailed link

- [Reading DTS and SSIS packages programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramoji/2008/09/29/reading-dts-and-ssis-packages-programmatically/)

There is another way *(harder way and not recommended)* to achieve this , by reading dtsx as text file and parse the xml content. check my answer at the following question to get an example:

- [Automate Version number Retrieval from .Dtsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591672/automate-version-number-retrieval-from-dtsx-files/43597141#43597141)

*Hint:*

*just open the package in visual studio. go to the `package explorer` Tab (near `control flow` and `data flow` tabs) you will find a treeview. it will leads you the way you have to search for the component you need*

[image]

---

### Update 1 - C# Script @ 2019-07-08

If you are looking for a script that list all package objects you can use a similar script:

```cs
using System;
using DtsRuntime = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using DtsWrapper = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

public void Main()
{
    string pkgLocation;
    DtsRuntime.Package pkg;
    DtsRuntime.Application app;
    DtsRuntime. DTSExecResult pkgResults;

    pkgLocation =
      @"D:\Test\Package 1.dtsx";
    app = new DtsRuntime.Application();
    pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

    //List Executables (Tasks)
    foreach(DtsRuntime.Executable tsk in pkg.Executables)
    {


        DtsRuntime.TaskHost TH = (DtsRuntime.TaskHost)tsk;
        MessageBox.Show(TH.Name + "\t" + TH.HostType.ToString());


        //Data Flow Task components
        if (TH.InnerObject.ToString() == "System.__ComObject")
        {
            try
            {

                DtsWrapper.MainPipe m = (DtsWrapper.MainPipe)TH.InnerObject;


                DtsWrapper.IDTSComponentMetaDataCollection100 mdc = m.ComponentMetaDataCollection;


                foreach (DtsWrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 md in mdc)


                {

                    MessageBox.Show(TH.Name.ToString() + " - " + md.Name.ToString());


                }

            }
            catch {

            // If it is not a data flow task then continue foreach loop

            }



        }



    }

    //Event Handlers
    foreach(DtsRuntime.DtsEventHandler eh in pkg.EventHandlers)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(eh.Name + " - " + CM.HostType);

    }

    //Connection Manager

    foreach(DtsRuntime.ConnectionManager CM in pkg.Connections)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(CM.Name + " - " + CM.HostType);


    }


    //Parameters
    foreach (DtsRuntime.Parameter Param in pkg.Parameters)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(Param.Name + " - " + Param.DataType.ToString());


    }


    //Variables
    foreach (DtsRuntime.Variable Var in pkg.Variables)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(Var.Name + " - " + Var.DataType.ToString());


    }

    //Precedence Constraints
    foreach (DtsRuntime.PrecedenceConstraint PC in pkg.PrecedenceConstraints)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(PC.Name);


    }

}
```

#### References

- [Loading and Running a Local Package Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/loading-and-running-a-local-package-programmatically?view=sql-server-2017)

---

### Update 2 - SSISPackageExplorer Project @ 2019-07-10

I started a small project called SSISPackageExplorer on Git-Hub which allow the user to read the package objects in a TreeView, It is very basic right now but i will try to improve it in a while:

- [GitHub - SSISPackageExplorer](https://github.com/HadiFadl/SSISPackageExplorer)

[image]

Comment: Hi Hadi,
How shall I extract the table name and column names from the query which SSIS package is using?

Comment: @SatishPatel i didn't know exactly, but i can give you a hint. check my answer update. also your question is too broad don't wait to get a very specific answer. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Some of the properties in dtsx Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline are not CLS-compliant.

- [ColumnInformation Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.columninformation.-ctor?view=sqlserver-2017#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Pipeline_ColumnInformation__ctor_System_String_Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Runtime_Wrapper_DataType_)

```
ColumnInformation Class 
Definition

Namespace:
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline 
Assembly:
Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll
Important
This API is not CLS-compliant.
C++

Copy
public ref class ColumnInformation
```

otherwise try this.

Just open your dtsx package in notepad++. Find table  name then do the same search on the property name in all packages( find ion all files). I think that even if you search for the column in dtsx opened in a text editor it will give you everything. It's manual but can be updated with Regex and c#. I never did it with regex. I just did notepad++ and one package once.

Comment: Have you checked the bounty notes? I am looking for a C# script, what you mentioned about using regex is mentioned in the answer provided. It is very hard to write a script using regex and it is not recommended since metadata may change in newer versions

Comment: did  you read my comment about msdn link? Column information is not possible in c#.

Comment: This API is not CLS-compliant.

Comment: I only need to show the packages tasks and components as mentioned in the Image above (Hadi's answer)

Comment: Sorry I am answering to Satish Patel answer. where it says source,destination and column names of source and destination. Why am I trying to do this is because I have thousands of packages and opening each package has on an average 60 to 75 of columns