# Automate Version number Retrieval from .Dtsx files

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

Is there a way or query by which I can find the version number of SSIS packages (*.dtsx files)?

I have the `*.dtsx` files in my Team Foundation Server for which I wanted to know.

The manual way is to do a mouse right-click on the package and click `Compare` to see the `VersionBuild` but there are like thousands of packages so doing it manually is really not possible

*Note: The process should be automated, not manual*

Comment: Take a look here: http://billfellows.blogspot.ca/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html (from this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04ca0a47-e514-434f-a92f-35864e16facd/how-to-determine-latest-version-of-ssis-deployed-to-msdb?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Alex this seems little related but I have the *.dtsx file in my TFS for which I wanted to know. The manual way is to right click on the package and click compare to see the VersionBuild but there are like thousands of packages so doing it manually is really not possible.

Comment: Your best bet is to write a C# console program that reads all the DTSX files for that property and compiles a list of their versions + names. It's just an XML file, so this will help you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-and-writing-xml-in-C-Sharp/. You could then write the values to a text file. The property you want to read is this one: http://www.techbrothersit.com/2014/09/ssis-how-to-find-version-of-ssis.html

Comment: @Alex i provided an answer on that take a look

Comment: Good job, @Hadi! Very nice, detailed answer. +1 :)

Comment: i don't know why th OP didn't accept this answer until now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Getting values within dtsx packages

- If you are trying to read a package version within this package you can access to one of the SSIS [system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables)

  ```
  Variable        Type    Description
  -------------------------------------------
  VersionBuild    Int32   The package version.
  VersionComment  String  Comments about the package version.
  VersionGUID     String  The unique identifier of the version.
  VersionMajor    Int32   The major version of the package.
  VersionMinor    Int32   The minor version of the package.
  ```
- If you are looking for Package SQL Server Version, you can find it inside the `dtsx` file if you open it as text (or xml) And search for `PackageFormatVersion` property, detailed informations are provided in the following links:

  - [SQL Studies - What SQL version is my SSIS package?](https://sqlstudies.com/2015/04/27/what-sql-version-is-my-ssis-package/) (this link contains the table writen below)
  - [MSDN - Package Format Changes in SQL Server Denali](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2011/08/10/package-format-changes-in-sql-server-denali/)

## Getting values from .dtsx files stored in Sql server

You can follow these links:

- [bill fellows article - SSIS package query](http://billfellows.blogspot.ca/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html?m=1)
- [Microsoft TechNet article - List all SSIS packages stored in msdb database](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSIS-packages-3b247394)

it contains queries that achieve this issue

## Getting values from .dtsx files not stored in Sql server

To automate reading `PackageFormatVersion` you can use read it programmatically using an `XMLParser` or `Regex`. I wrote a code in Vb.net that use `Regex` and loop over `.dtsx` files inside a directory and get the `PackageFormatVersion` property and other properties found in dtsx file header:

- PackageFileName
- PackageFormatVersion
- CreationDate
- CreationName
- CreatorComputerName
- CreatorName
- DTSID
- ExecutableType
- LastModifiedProductVersion
- LocaleID
- ObjectName
- PackageType
- VersionBuild
- VersionGUID

First i created a Class named `PackageInfo` that contains properties listed above

```
Public Class PackageInfo

    Public Property PackageFileName As String
    Public Property PackageFormatVersion As String
    Public Property CreationDate As String
    Public Property CreationName As String
    Public Property CreatorComputerName As String
    Public Property CreatorName As String
    Public Property DTSID As String
    Public Property ExecutableType As String
    Public Property LastModifiedProductVersion As String
    Public Property LocaleID As String
    Public Property ObjectName As String
    Public Property PackageType As String
    Public Property VersionBuild As String
    Public Property VersionGUID As String


End Class
```

**Using RegEx**

```
Private Sub ReadPackagesInfo(ByVal strDirectory As String)


        m_lst.Clear()

        For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory, "*.dtsx", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)


            Dim strContent As String = ""

            Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(strFile)

                strContent = sr.ReadToEnd
                sr.Close()

            End Using


            Dim strPackageFormatVersion As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=""PackageFormatVersion"">)(.*)(?=</DTS:Property>)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strCreationDate As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:CreationDate="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strCreationName As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:CreationName="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strCreatorComputerName As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:CreatorComputerName="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strCreatorName As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:CreatorName="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strDTSID As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:DTSID="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strExecutableType As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:ExecutableType="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strLastModifiedProductVersion As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strLocaleID As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:LocaleID="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strObjectName As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:ObjectName="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strPackageType As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:PackageType="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strVersionBuild As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:VersionBuild="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
            Dim strVersionGUID As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=DTS:VersionGUID="")(.*?)(?="")", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value



            m_lst.Add(New PackageInfo With {.PackageFileName = strFile,
                      .PackageFormatVersion = strPackageFormatVersion,
                      .CreationDate = strCreationDate,
                      .CreationName = strCreationName,
                      .CreatorComputerName = strCreatorComputerName,
                      .CreatorName = strCreatorName,
                      .DTSID = strDTSID,
                      .ExecutableType = strExecutableType,
                      .LastModifiedProductVersion = strLastModifiedProductVersion,
                      .LocaleID = strLocaleID,
                      .ObjectName = strObjectName,
                      .PackageType = strPackageType,
                      .VersionBuild = strVersionBuild,
                     .VersionGUID = strVersionGUID})


        Next



End Sub
```

The following line of code is the one that read the `PackageFormatVersion` property from the file

```
Dim strA As String = Regex.Match(strContent, "(?<=""PackageFormatVersion"">)(.*)(?=</DTS:Property>)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
```

**Using Xml Parser**

```
    Private Sub ReadPackagesInfoUsingXmlParser(ByVal strDirectory As String)

        m_lst.Clear()

        For Each strFile As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirectory, "*.dtsx", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            Dim strPackageFormatVersion As String = ""
            Dim strCreationDate As String = ""
            Dim strCreationName As String = ""
            Dim strCreatorComputerName As String = ""
            Dim strCreatorName As String = ""
            Dim strDTSID As String = ""
            Dim strExecutableType As String = ""
            Dim strLastModifiedProductVersion As String = ""
            Dim strLocaleID As String = ""
            Dim strObjectName As String = ""
            Dim strPackageType As String = ""
            Dim strVersionBuild As String = ""
            Dim strVersionGUID As String = ""


            Dim xml = XDocument.Load(strFile)

            Dim ns As XNamespace = "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
            Dim man As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(New NameTable())
            man.AddNamespace("DTS", "www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")

            If Not xml.Root Is Nothing AndAlso
                Not xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Property").Attributes(ns + "Name") Is Nothing AndAlso
                     xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Property").Attributes(ns + "Name").Where(Function(x) x.Value = "PackageFormatVersion").Count > 0 Then

                strPackageFormatVersion = xml.Root.Descendants(ns + "Property").Attributes(ns + "Name").Where(Function(x) x.Value = "PackageFormatVersion").FirstOrDefault.Parent.Value

                strCreationDate = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreationDate").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreationDate").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strCreationName = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreationName").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreationName").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strCreatorComputerName = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreatorComputerName").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreatorComputerName").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strCreatorName = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreatorName").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "CreatorName").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strDTSID = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "DTSID").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "DTSID").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strExecutableType = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "ExecutableType").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "ExecutableType").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strLastModifiedProductVersion = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "LastModifiedProductVersion").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "LastModifiedProductVersion").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strLocaleID = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "LocaleID").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "LocaleID").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strObjectName = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "ObjectName").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "ObjectName").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strPackageType = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "PackageType").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "PackageType").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strVersionBuild = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "VersionBuild").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "VersionBuild").FirstOrDefault.Value)
                strVersionGUID = If(xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "VersionGUID").FirstOrDefault Is Nothing, "", xml.Root.Attributes(ns + "VersionGUID").FirstOrDefault.Value)
            End If



            m_lst.Add(New PackageInfo With {.PackageFileName = strFile,
                      .PackageFormatVersion = strPackageFormatVersion,
                      .CreationDate = strCreationDate,
                      .CreationName = strCreationName,
                      .CreatorComputerName = strCreatorComputerName,
                      .CreatorName = strCreatorName,
                      .DTSID = strDTSID,
                      .ExecutableType = strExecutableType,
                      .LastModifiedProductVersion = strLastModifiedProductVersion,
                      .LocaleID = strLocaleID,
                      .ObjectName = strObjectName,
                      .PackageType = strPackageType,
                      .VersionBuild = strVersionBuild,
                     .VersionGUID = strVersionGUID})

        Next

    End Sub
```

**Demo App**

I Created A Demo Application to achieve this procedure you can download it from the following link:

- [Dropbox download link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/23eft9xzn1rmfhj/GetDTSXVersion.zip?dl=0)

*Also i created a new [Git-repository](https://github.com/HadiFadl/GetDTSXInfos) for this demo app*

***App screenshot***

[image]

## Getting values from .dtsx files Using TSQL

You can Read my answer at DBA.StackExchange :

- [Determine the PackageFormatVersion for multiple .DTSX packages files in a folder](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/determine-the-packageformatversion-for-multiple-dtsx-packages-files-in-a-folder/171871#171871)

## PackageFormatVersion Table

And Here is the `PackageFormatVersion` table values

```
SQL Version Build # PackageFormatVersion    Visual Studio Version
2005        9       2                       2005
2008        10      3                       2008
2008 R2     10.5    3                       2008
2012        11      6                       2010 or BI 2012
2014        12      8                       2012 CTP2 or 2013
2016        13      8                       2015
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Hadi, I have never worked in Vb but I can try your solution. Also, Just to add that my all packages are in server not on local, I access them via Visual Studio. I was just wondering how can I use vb code to get the required info from server.

Comment: Few hours and i will provide a demo application link

Comment: The code i provided is a function that get a directory as arguments. Loop over dtsx files and get their versions into a list.

Comment: @saurabhsharma files in tfs are mapped to a local path so changes are made local until they are checked in. So in the team explorer in visual studio right click on a package and click on `Open containing folder`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution and all your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this query if you use project deployment solution (If you have SSISDB in your server) :

```
SELECT 
   [name],
   [package_format_version]
FROM [SSISDB].[catalog].[packages];
```

*Note: Integration Services must be installed*

Comment: I don't know why I have gotten the negative point?!? But still I think that you should deploy all your packages to SSIS and then run the above query.

Comment: I gave you a vote too. Pretty simple if you have saved it in the SSISDB. The more I use SSISDB the more I like it.

Comment: @JacobH SSISDB is pretty good, but the question is about automating this process? i don't think this query is what the OP is asking for

Comment: @lahmbajin the question is a way to query for the version number of the package. When the package is stored in the SSISDB, the version is stored in the catalog.packages table. Just a select statement. Put it in whatever automation you need (log, sproc, etc.) just as you would any select statement.

Comment: @JacobH if you read the OP comments ` I have the *.dtsx file in my TFS for which I wanted to know.` , he is not talking about dtsx stored in sql server

Comment: @lahmbajin Deploy temporary your project to SQL Server and run this query to find version of all package that you have.

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi it is simpler to use a third-party application like the one provided in Hadi answer

Comment: @ArdalanShahgoli Even if the OP accepted my answer. i upvoted your answer because it is also a good way to solve the issue.

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi i provided an answer to a similar question at DBA site check it out https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/determine-the-packageformatversion-for-multiple-dtsx-packages-files-in-a-folder

Answer (score 2):

`.ispac` file is zip file actually and every `.dtsx` is XML file with all required information inside it. additionally to answer that friends sent,XML itself hold all of information that you want.[image]

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: the OP said `The process should be automated, not manual.`, so we are searching for a way to automate reading this values from the xml. Take a look at Hadi answer, he is in the right way, but i am searching for the optimal method if it exists

Comment: What is `.ispac` ? Does it have a relation with this question?

Comment: `.ispac` is deployed file of SSIS package @lahmbajin

Comment: @YasharAliabasi upvoted ur answer. Because it is where we have to start. Take a look at my answer you can consider it as the next step to your answer. Good luck