# Changing connection managers from SQLNCLI11.1 to SQLOLEDB.1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I've been doing some porting of old SSIS packages from a legacy system into a new system. I was running some tests only to see some kind of error output related to the ODBC connection with Code: 0xC0202009.

The package's two connection managers are both built with SQLNCLI11.1 as the provider.

[image]

I believe I can fix the error if I switch that to SQLOLEDB.1. Is there a simple way to do that without having to rebuild the entire package from scratch? Is there an XML file somewhere I can just replace the old value with the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to open the package (.dtsx) file with a text editor (notepad, notepad++). And search for this property and replace it manually. (*.Dtsx file is  an xml file*)

But replacing this property may cause other errors if each provider has different properties. So Take a backup of these packages before editing.

Take a look at this question it may help you (check my answer and the others. It will give you an idea on how a dtsx file can be readed outside of visual studio):

- [Automate Version number Retrieval from .Dtsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591672/automate-version-number-retrieval-from-dtsx-files/)