# SSIS import CSV file to existing table, using data type and sizes

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I have an existing table in SQL Server to which a CSV file must be loaded. Using a `Flat File Source` comes up with the correct line endings and delimiter character. However, every column is configured as `DataType = DT_STR` and `OutputColumnWidth = 50`.

Is there any way to have the *Flat File Source* use the table to set the `DataType` and `OutputColumnWidth` correctly? This seems like a lot of work to do manually.

Comment: Why not select columns with similar types *(i.e. containing numeric values)* and change them at once?

Answer (score 1):

> This seems like a lot of work to do manually

**Not always!** You can select multiple columns and change their data types and width at once from the *Flat File Connection Manager > Advanced Tab*.

You can simply open the Flat File Connection Manager, Go To Advanced Tab, Click on one Column, Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and select all needed columns then change the `DataType` and `OutputColumnWidth` properties. *(You can note that once you select multiple columns, only common properties are shown)*

[image]

- [SSIS Flat File Connection - How does it determine string column DataType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284312/ssis-flat-file-connection-how-does-it-determine-string-column-datatype/56284322#56284322)

> Is there any way to have the Flat File Source use the table to set the DataType and OutputColumnWidth correctly?

**You should build your package programmatically or use BIML scripts**. You can check the following articles for more information:

- [Getting Started with Biml](https://www.sqlshack.com/getting-started-with-biml/)
- [Creating packages using the Integration Services managed object model](https://www.sqlshack.com/biml-alternatives-building-ssis-packages-programmatically-using-manageddts/)
- [Creating SSIS package using EzApi library](https://www.sqlshack.com/biml-alternatives-building-ssis-packages-programmatically-using-ezapi/)

Another alternative ***(that I don't recommend)*** is to edit the .dtsx package with a text editor and replace the Maxiumum Width property value.

- [SSIS: Flat File default length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964823/ssis-flat-file-default-length/45786421#45786421)