# SSIS package name which updated table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

Please help me to get SSIS package details based table name.

Eg: I have a table `A` which is update based on ssis package. so i would like to name of that package.

Is there any query i can get it from back end.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: you can get the package name as a audit column from the etl by using the pre-defined system variable - PackageName

Comment: Dheerendra - i dont want to create any new packages. there are some packages scheduled already and i know the table name which loading from packages. i want to know the which package is loading from the table name

Answer (score 1):

SSIS packages are basically just XML-files, so you can open it in some text editor and then use the editors Find-function to locate references to your table.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no Log files, or an audit table created to store these informations, you cannot find the package that updated a specific table.

There is a workaround that you can do, is to search the packages that contains the table name. if you are interested in this approach, you can read my answer @ [Automate Version number Retrieval from .Dtsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591672/automate-version-number-retrieval-from-dtsx-files/43597141#43597141)