# Can the same SSIS ETL Product (Package) work for SSIS for SQL Server 2014 and 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2016, ssis-2014

We're building an ETL Product in SSIS. A lot of our SSIS packages have script tasks written in C# script with assembly references to Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS etc.

Some of our customers may be using an older version of SQL (2014) while some may upgrade to 2016.

What is the industry standard and best practice for such situations, where you can release newer product versions to both set of customers using old and new SQL Server versions?

Is there any way we can support both SQL Server 2014 and 2016 without having to maintain 2 code bases?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2014 and 2016 ssis package has the same `PackageFormatVersion` which is `8`but the ManagedDTS.dll version differs between two versions.

- For SQL Server 2014, version is 12.0.0.0
- For SQL Server 2016, version is 13.0.0.0

For these reason, you cannot work with both version from the same application, because you must decide to choose between one of these DLL's.

**Useful Links**

- [Automate Version number Retrieval from .Dtsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591672/automate-version-number-retrieval-from-dtsx-files/43597141#43597141)
- [What SQL version is my package?](https://sqlstudies.com/2015/04/27/what-sql-version-is-my-ssis-package/)