# Parse SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, xml-parsing, etl

I have several .dtsx packages in the folder on file system.
 I try to extract additional information from the package with next script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts;

namespace ImportDataFromPackage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //  The pkg variable points to a package
            //  installed with the SSIS samples.
            string pkg = @"D:\MyFolder\Ryder_project\testpackage\ACS\ACS_Available_Months.dtsx";

            Application app = new Application();
            Package p1 = app.LoadPackage(pkg, null);
            p1.Description = "CalculatedColumns package";

            app.SaveToDtsServer(p1, null, @"File System\myp1Package", "YOURSERVER");
            PackageInfos pInfos = app.GetDtsServerPackageInfos(@"File System", "YOURSERVER");
            foreach (PackageInfo pinfo in pInfos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Package Information");
                Console.WriteLine("CreationDate:        {0}", pinfo.CreationDate);
                Console.WriteLine("Description:         {0}", pinfo.Description);
                Console.WriteLine("Flags:               {0}", pinfo.Flags);
                Console.WriteLine("Folder:              {0}", pinfo.Folder);
                Console.WriteLine("Name:                {0}", pinfo.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("PackageDataSize:     {0}", pinfo.PackageDataSize);
                Console.WriteLine("PackageGuid:         {0}", pinfo.PackageGuid);
                Console.WriteLine("VersionBuild:        {0}", pinfo.VersionBuild);
                Console.WriteLine("VersionComments      {0}", pinfo.VersionComments);
                Console.WriteLine("VersionGUID          {0}", pinfo.VersionGUID);
                Console.WriteLine("VersionMajor         {0}", pinfo.VersionMajor);
                Console.WriteLine("VersionMinor         {0}", pinfo.VersionMinor);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

and I get next error:

[image]

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is the package actually located in the D:\MyFolder location on the server? Or is that local?

Comment: That is a local disc D:\  on my PC.

Comment: So I assume you are running these packages from the server, which means it will be looking at the local D:\ drive there.

Answer (score 2):

SSIS packages `.dtsx` files are Xml files, so you can use XML Parser and other techniques, Regular Expressions to get its informations. You can achieve this using SQL, .Net and other technologies.

You can follow my detailed answer to the following question:

- [Automate Version number Retrieval from .Dtsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591672/automate-version-number-retrieval-from-dtsx-files/43597141)

Also if you are looking for a reverse engineering you can check the following link:

- [Reverse engineering SSIS package using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562611/reverse-engineering-ssis-package-using-c-sharp/43569331#43569331)

Comment: Nice scripts. Thanks a lot. Could you be so kind to tell me how I can get from .dtsx package (from Connection manager: refId)?

Comment: @Andrey your always welcomed :) i really don't know how to retrieve it. It needs some experiments to get it. You must know its pattern to search for it using Regex or you must know its path to get it using xml parsing.

Comment: ok. I just thought you know how to work with parent-child relationships using regex or xml parsing)

Comment: Good!! It will be an added value to the scripts i provided.

Comment: mb, we can connect in skype for a while to resolve this question?