# Pressing mappings in the Data Flow Task using .Net

Tags: c#, sql-server, powershell, ssis, etl

I asked this question a couple of weeks ago:

["Pressing" the mapping tabs in the Data Flow Task without opening the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180771/pressing-the-mapping-tabs-in-the-data-flow-task-without-opening-the-solution)

Now I can load the package object in PowerShell with this code:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll';

$pkg = "C:\test.dtsx";

$app = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application 

$app | Get-Member

$Package = $app.LoadPackage($pkg, $null, $FALSE)

$Package | Get-Member

$Package.Executables

$DataFlowTask = $Package.Executables | Where-Object {$_.('Description') -eq ("Data Flow Task")};
```

My goal is to refresh the metadata (mappings) in the Data Flow task in both the destination and source.

I would like to call these methods on the object, which I think should do the trick (see this [Link](https://www.sqlshack.com/biml-alternatives-building-ssis-packages-programmatically-using-manageddts/))

```cs
instance.AcquireConnections(null);
instance.ReinitializeMetaData();
instance.ReleaseConnections();
```

But I cannot find the Data Flow Object in the package object created above. What is the "address" on the Data Flow Task in the package object?

Comment: Are you looking for a PowerShell solution? Why not use C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this can be done using PowerShell, but I will give the C# solution.

```cs
//loop over control flow tasks
foreach (DtsRuntime.Executable tsk in pkg.Executables)
{
    DtsRuntime.TaskHost TH = (DtsRuntime.TaskHost)tsk
    //Getting the data flow task object
    if (TH.InnerObject.ToString() == "System.__ComObject")
    {
        try
        {
            DtsWrapper.MainPipe m = (DtsWrapper.MainPipe)TH.InnerObject;
            DtsWrapper.IDTSComponentMetaDataCollection100 mdc = m.ComponentMetaDataCollection;
            //loop over data flow task components
            foreach (DtsWrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 md in mdc)
            {
                //get the OLE DB Destination component                
                if(md.ComponentClassID == app.PipelineComponentInfos["OLE DB Destination"].CreationName)
                {
                 //add your code here
                }             
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This code was taken and improved from the following answer: [Reverse engineering SSIS package using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562611/reverse-engineering-ssis-package-using-c-sharp/43569331#43569331)

---

I don't have much experience in PowerShell, but I will try to provide some helpful links:

- [Get-SsisMetadata.ps1](https://github.com/BeginTry/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-SsisMetadata.ps1)
- [How to create SSIS package with PowerShell?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/330b2402-0350-4e7c-9e79-f5b24ba23ec1/how-to-create-ssis-package-with-powershell-i-get-providecomponentproperties-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices) *(This link contain a method that execute a C# script from PowerShell - it may help)*

Comment: Hi, I still cannot find the ReinitializeMetaData() method? I have ComponentMetaDataCollection for the Data Flow Task, but there is no such method for the objects after that... Any hints?

Comment: You should loop over the data flow task component and check if the component class is an OLE DB destination as I mention above. The method should be called where i placed the comment : `add your code here`

Comment: Hi again, I cannot find Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll. Is it nessasary for DtsWrapper.MainPipe? It is not in GAC nor in the SQL Server folder in Program files (SQL Server 2019).

Comment: @xhr489 make sure that the Integrations Services shared feature is installed with SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Hi, `Microsoft.SqlServer.RuntimeWrapper.dll` is not to be found anywhere on any computer. I have even tried `Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\" -Filter *RuntimeWrapper.dll -Recurse -Force` and no luck. See also this question [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308877/finding-a-sql-server-assembly-where-is-100-folder-in-the-installation-folder) where I have asked the question on DBA website.

Comment: Try searching for `DTSRuntimeWrap.dll`

Comment: Hi I have found it, but the 64 bit only covers until sql server 2017. I think I need a 64 bit for sql server 2019 for the PowerShell to work.