# Script to run to list the Connection Manager used by each control

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2008, ssis-2016

### Background

Migrating from SSIS2008 to 2016. Using SSDT2015

### Question

Is there a script or any automation method to quickly list the Connection Managers used by all controls *(both in Control Flow and Data Flow)* in a project?  Currently I'm opening each control to identify the Connection Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy solution for your question, you have to *"deserialize"* the ssis package, you can do this programmatically using C# or Vb.net or you have to use regular expressions. You can get more info from this question: [Reverse engineering SSIS package using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562611/reverse-engineering-ssis-package-using-c-sharp/43569331#43569331)