# View content of dtsx file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, etl

I have Import.dtsx in Integration Services Catalog in my SQL Server Managment Studio. Unsuccessfully there is no Import.dtsx file in any place on HDD. I have no idea what transformation occurs during processing this dtsx.
Is there any way to view it’s content in SSMS?

Comment: Not in SSMS, no. You'll need to extract the package from instance into a project.

Comment: you can "import" a deployed package into a SSIS project in Visual Studio

Comment: You may find this useful [Reverse engineering SSIS package using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562611/reverse-engineering-ssis-package-using-c-sharp/43569331#43569331)

Answer (score 0):

No, SSMS has no concept of editing or displaying layout of an SSIS package.

PragmaticWorks used to have an SSIS documenter product which was likely included in the sale to SQL Sentry/SentryOne. That product would open a package and create a .chm (Help) file of what the package does.

The other options I know of would be to use either download and install [BimlStudio](https://varigence.com/bimlstudio) (free trial registration) or see if BimlOnline.com works. Either way, the products will decompile an SSIS package into Biml. The Biml tools then offer a GUI to interact with the package.

The final option would be to open the package with a text editor and beyond pulling out high level tasks, search for DTS:Description, that's not a pain I'd wish on anyone.

Comment: Why use 3rd party tools? What's wrong with the tool used to create them: Visual Studio with the SSIS extension?

Comment: @Larnu Based on their comments, I presumed the reason the reason they were looking to use SSMS was because Visual Studio and/or the Business Intelligence Design Studio/SQL Server Data Tools componentry was not available