# Translating C# to PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to translate this code from C# to PowerShell

```sh
//Creating a new package
Application app = new Application();
Package p = new Package();

//Adding the connection manager
ConnectionManager DatabaseConnectionManager = p.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
DatabaseConnectionManager.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Auto Translate=false;"; ;
DatabaseConnectionManager.Name = "ConnectionOLEDB";
DatabaseConnectionManager.Description = "SSIS Connection Manager for OLEDB";
    
//Adding the data flow task
Executable e = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
TaskHost thMainPipe = (TaskHost)e;
MainPipe dataFlowTask = (MainPipe)thMainPipe.InnerObject;
thMainPipe.Name = "Import Person";
    
IDTSComponentMetaData100 component = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
component.Name = "OLEDBSource";
component.ComponentClassID = app.PipelineComponentInfos["OLE DB Source"].CreationName;
```

Code this from this webpage under the section "**Adding Data Flow Tasks components**": https://www.sqlshack.com/biml-alternatives-building-ssis-packages-programmatically-using-manageddts/

The assemblies are:

```sh
using System;
using DtsRuntime = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using DtsWrapper = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
```

See [Reverse engineering SSIS package using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562611/reverse-engineering-ssis-package-using-c-sharp/43569331#43569331)

My problems start at the line with `TaskHost thMainPipe = (TaskHost)e;` and I get the errors like "Cannot convert ...value of type ...".

Here is the PowerShell code that is working:

```sh
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll';
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll';
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll';
 # Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll';

$App = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application; 
$Package = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package;
$PackageFullPath = 'C:\test.dtsx';
# Empty package created. 

$ConnectionString = "Data Source=SomeInstance;Initial Catalog=SomeDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";
 
$DatabaseConnectionManager = $Package.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
$DatabaseConnectionManager.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString;
$DatabaseConnectionManager.Name = "SomeDB";
$DatabaseConnectionManager.Description = "Hello";

# Add a Data Flow Task
$e = $Package.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");

  # $App.SaveToXml($PackageFullPath, $Package,$null);
```

Why am I getting a cast error for `TaskHost thMainPipe = (TaskHost)e;`?

Where I get the error is:

```sh
# Add a Data Flow Task
$e = $Package.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask"); # This works
# $e | Get-Member
$thMainPipe = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost]$e # no error here
# This line triggers the error:
$dataFlowTask = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe]$thMainPipe.InnerObject
```

The error message is:

```sh
Cannot convert the "System.__ComObject" value of type "System.__ComObject#{b3350f87-4de7-4cb4-a273-d980c9e0b8ad}" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe".
At line:1 char:1
+ $dataFlowTask = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe]$t ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Also the type of `$e` is `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost`. So not sure why I need `$thMainPipe`at all.

Comment: Does it work if you just do `$thMainPipe.InnerObject.Name = "Import Person"` directly (eg. skip the explicit cast entirely)?

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks, $thMainPipe.InnerObject.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New() works

Comment: This is a strange request. You are converting a SSIS script task to Powershell and preserving all of the SSIS objects. I'm not sure of the objectives here but if you are undertaking a refactoring exercise, you should consider a solution that no longer requires SSIS.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I agree, I would rather use Python, BIML, Linked Server or Polybase. What can I say, bad management decisions...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: the good news is that I am learning PowerShell and it is pretty cool.

Comment: Gotta take the positives right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>See also: [This follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71510337/45375).</sup>

That your cast's operand is a *COM object* (as evidenced by `System.__ComObject` being reported as the object type in the error message) may be the source of the problem, because I don't think PowerShell can cast COM objects to other types.

However, given that PowerShell can dynamically discover members on objects, **in many cases where C# requires casts, PowerShell doesn't** (and casts to *interfaces* are no-ops in PowerShell, except when guiding method overload resolution). Similarly, there's **no (strict) need to *type variables*.**<sup>[1]</sup>

Thus, as you've confirmed, simply *omitting* the cast of `$thMainPipe.InnerObject` to type `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe]` worked:

```sh
$dataFlowTask = $thMainPipe.InnerObject # No cast.
$component = $dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New()
```

---

<sup>[1] Typing a variable in PowerShell means to *type-constrain* it, which means that you're still free to assign a value of any type, as long as PowerShell can automatically *convert* it to the target type (and PowerShell's automatic type conversions are very flexible); e.g., `[int] $num = '42'` works fine. *Without* a type constraint, the type of the value being assigned, which may be of any type, effectively determines its type, but you're free to assign an object of a different type later; e.g. `$var = '42'` makes `$var` contain a `[string]`, whereas `$var = 42` makes it an `[int]`.</sup>