# PowerShell not guessing .Net Type correctly

Tags: c#, powershell

PowerShell Version:

[image]

This question is a continuation of the problem I am trying to solve from this post: [Translating C# to PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488991/translating-c-sharp-to-powershell). The C# code works and is basically a copy-paste from this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/biml-alternatives-building-ssis-packages-programmatically-using-manageddts/ (the section "Adding Data Flow Tasks components").

I have created the source and destination database with the following code:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestingCSharp;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestingCsharpSource](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [txt] [char](5) NULL
); 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestingCsharpSource](txt) VALUES('Hello')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestingCsharpDestination](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [txt] [char](5) NULL
);
GO
```

The C# code that is working:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
    
    
    
    namespace SSIS_package_building
    {
        class Package_building
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var P_b = new Package_building();
                P_b.CreateSYSTPackage();
            }
    
            public void CreateSYSTPackage()
            {
                //Creating a new package
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package p = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package();
    
                //Adding the connection manager
                ConnectionManager DatabaseConnectionManager = p.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
                DatabaseConnectionManager.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestingCSharp;Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Auto Translate=false;"; 
                DatabaseConnectionManager.Name = "ConnectionOLEDB";
                DatabaseConnectionManager.Description = "SSIS Connection Manager for OLEDB";
    
                //Adding the data flow task
                Executable e = p.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
                Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost thMainPipe = (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost)e;
                MainPipe dataFlowTask = (MainPipe)thMainPipe.InnerObject;
                thMainPipe.Name = "Import Person";
    
                IDTSComponentMetaData100 component = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
                component.Name = "OLEDBSource";
                component.ComponentClassID = app.PipelineComponentInfos["OLE DB Source"].CreationName;
    
                //Get the design-time instance of the component.  
                CManagedComponentWrapper instance = component.Instantiate();
    
                //Initialize the component.  
                instance.ProvideComponentProperties();
    
                //Map the component to a connection manager
                component.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(p.Connections[0]);
                component.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = DatabaseConnectionManager.ID;
    
                //Set the OLE DB Source properties
                instance.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 2);
                instance.SetComponentProperty("SqlCommand", "Select * FROM TestingCsharpSource");
    
                // Reinitialize the metadata.  
                instance.AcquireConnections(null);
                instance.ReinitializeMetaData();
                instance.ReleaseConnections();
    
                // Create the destination component.  
                IDTSComponentMetaData100 destination = dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
                destination.ComponentClassID = app.PipelineComponentInfos["OLE DB Destination"].CreationName;
    
                var destinationInstance = destination.Instantiate();
                destinationInstance.ProvideComponentProperties();
    
                destination.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManagerID = DatabaseConnectionManager.ID;
                destination.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0].ConnectionManager = DtsConvert.GetExtendedInterface(p.Connections[0]);
    
                destinationInstance.SetComponentProperty("AccessMode", 3);
                destinationInstance.SetComponentProperty("OpenRowset", "[dbo].[TestingCsharpDestination]");
    
                // Create the path.  
                IDTSPath100 path = dataFlowTask.PathCollection.New();
                path.AttachPathAndPropagateNotifications(component.OutputCollection[0], destination.InputCollection[0]);
    
                //Get the destination's default input and virtual input.
                IDTSInput100 input = destination.InputCollection[0];
                IDTSVirtualInput100 vInput = input.GetVirtualInput();
                IDTSVirtualInputColumnCollection100 vInputColumns = vInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection;
    
                destinationInstance.AcquireConnections(null);
                destinationInstance.ReinitializeMetaData();
                destinationInstance.ReleaseConnections();
    
                //Iterate through the virtual input column collection.  
                foreach (IDTSVirtualInputColumn100 vColumn in vInputColumns)
                {
                    var inputColumn = destinationInstance.SetUsageType(input.ID, vInput, vColumn.LineageID, DTSUsageType.UT_READONLY);
                    var externalColumn = input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection[inputColumn.Name];
                    destinationInstance.MapInputColumn(input.ID, inputColumn.ID, externalColumn.ID);
    
                }
    
                app.SaveToXml(@"C:\test.dtsx", p, null);
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

The PowerShell code is:(the error happens at the last line):

```
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll';
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap.dll';
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost.dll';
    Add-Type -path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll';



$app = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application; 
$p = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package;

$PackageFullPath = 'C:\testdeleteme.dtsx';
# Adding the connection manager
$DatabaseConnectionManager = $p.Connections.Add("OLEDB");
$DatabaseConnectionManager.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=TestingCSharp;Integrated Security=SSPI;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Auto Translate=false;"; 
$DatabaseConnectionManager.Name = "ConnectionOLEDB";
$DatabaseConnectionManager.Description = "SSIS Connection Manager for OLEDB";

# Adding the data flow task
$e = $p.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask");
$thMainPipe = $e;
# [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe]
$dataFlowTask = $thMainPipe.InnerObject;
$thMainPipe.Name = "Import Person";

# [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100]
$component = $dataFlowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
$component.Name = "OLEDBSource";
$component.ComponentClassID = $app.PipelineComponentInfos["OLE DB Source"].CreationName;

# Get the design-time instance of the component.  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.CManagedComponentWrapper]
$instance = $component.Instantiate();

# Initialize the component.  
$instance.ProvideComponentProperties();
```

The error message is:

```
Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))
At line:1 char:1
+ $instance.ProvideComponentProperties()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

The output of `$instance | Get-Member` is:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject

Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type requestedType)
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()
GetType                   Method     type GetType()
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()
ToString                  Method     string ToString()
```

So the method `ProvideComponentProperties()` is not there and the Type is from `System`. So I guess it does not guess the Type correctly.

My computer is 64 bit and I have tried the code in a 32 bit session and the error message is the same.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243082/discussion-on-question-by-xhr489-powershell-not-guessing-net-type-correctly).

Comment: Powershell doesn't do COM Interop the same way as C# and VB.NET.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/creating-.net-and-com-objects--new-object-?view=powershell-7.2#creating-com-objects-with-new-object